# Time complexity when loop index is an exponent

Tags: time-complexity, runtime-analysis, loops

For any $n$ and any $x$, if one implements a loop to calculate:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n x^i$$

What is time complexity of said loop if we assume $x^i$ to have time complexity of $O(i)$?

What confuses me is the fact that in each iteration, $i$ will have a different value.

Comment: May be helpful https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression

Answer (score 1):

With your assumption that computing $x^i$ has $O(i)$ complexity, the iteration with some $i$ will have complexity of $O(i)$ too (it simply adds $x^i$ to the current sum). So, complexity of each iteration can be taken $ci$ for some $c$. Total complexity of all iterations:

$ \sum_{i=1}^{n} ci = cn(n+1)/2 $

which belongs to $O(n^2)$.

But for an efficient method, you can refer to the formula for sum of a geometric progression.

Comment: So, because the $i$ in $O(i)$ of each iteration can vary, we take it as its worse, which is $i=n$, to then arrive at $O(ni)=O(n²)$?

Comment: If we take the internal steps' complexity as a loose bound (far from precise), we may get the final total complexity as loose too. So, generally it is a better idea to not replace $i$ by $n$ (though, in this case, you would arrive at the same answer $O(n^2)$).